# dot net web Application crashes with encrypted message everytime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I just configured my Visual studio 2010 with IIS express 8.0. It works perfectly but in case of any error in my code it is showing me crash page in encrypted format (Meaning - It shows full of boxes and some special characters). So every time i need to go event viewer to check the issue. Can you please help me in this?

This is how the message looks:
��`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��Ey�')=��y6�����h���8]�����u]���u�-�������Gi[,�ߪ�?��WZ4i���uQ��t������>z��YQ6�Ҽ����*��S����YQ���|9+�O�f �ϫly�����A���U��?�_��`�����������������w�n<=>9��ypzr��/׫�:�]�W�b]f�/\N���ٲ%����G�(Eӏ�b���(��>�� 1~�]/����K���=^����Xe���1��Y����2�޼6�u�A:�f��/>����y�(��G�d^ϲe��!z���ђh���QS� �����iUV��I�M���ԃ�z�>�EV_���Z=J���������T���������f�����Z�s���� �-H¸���U�w�|=-fYzR-�������|��<&�o�Z()*�S!U��k�g����o��j��.�_�/^��u؂�/��J�Iն��Q���z�i�n�-gل���ݞ��Y^����H�8/���CMC� ԡO��w}V|W���\?�`@�}t5/��#����G���{�:�iܩU(��8=^��b�؎��������vwv~���ٮ��YS���������|�(}\�l������-��b{4��3�y���4�������Q���آ%������~�^/*g�f�U~AT$D���uq�F�sr�>͛i]�DVߝ/���P���i�ߥՔ�������2o����f�19h���|E�n��;������}x��:I*~��e���N��5�ϑ�I~�h�}��JV>ͧ��f,x��'.���ﶮʒ�b�N�I�5���>ْ_2K4�*�s��9$r��U������M�Hw�ӺZ���C����{������lIf.?c3��wg<|���ϧ�t ��wgD�������{�h��o�-��fE/���(����@��Q���lY��9nɖ�

Comment: post a screenshot of your 'encrypted' page? could it just be an encoding issue? can you temporarily change your regional settings to US to see what happens?

Comment: Yes. My regional settings is already set to US. I need 10 reputations for posting images :-( sorry.

Comment: use http://imgur.com/ to share images. do you have fiddler installed or able to install it? are you able to inspect what you get back raw from IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved the issue. Initially my application was working in integrated mode. I tried it with classic app pool and it started showing the real error message :-)